# Implicit function theorem $xz^3+yu+ax=1, 2xy^3+u^2z+a(y-1)=0$

Tags: implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

So I have this two equations, $$xz^3+yu+ax=1$$ $$2xy^3+u^2z+a(y-1)=0$$ that define (x,y) as an implicit function of (z,u) in a neighbourhood of the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0,u_0)=(0,1,0,1)$. Now, if we call $(x,y)=G(u,z)$, I need to know for which values of *a*, G admits a local inverse of $C^1$ class in a neighbourhood of the point $(0,1)$. My procedure is:

Using the implicit function theorem, we know that $$\text{Jacobian}G(0,1)=-\begin{pmatrix}
a & 1 \\
2 & a \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{a^2-2} &  \frac{-a}{a^2-2} \\
\frac{-a}{a^2-2} &  \frac{2}{a^2-2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which determinant is $\frac{2-a^2}{a^2-2}=0 \Leftrightarrow a=\pm \sqrt{2}$, so in conclusion, G admits local inverse for every value of *a* except $\pm \sqrt{2}$

I want to know if my solution is correct.

Comment: I think you do not need to compute this matrix product, only the product of the determinants. And $a\ne\pm\sqrt2$ is already a necessary condition to apply the implicit function theorem and prove the *existence* of $G.$ And the existence of $G^{-1}$ is the existence of an implicit function $(u,z)=H(x,y).$ You can check directly that $H$ always exists around that point (contrarily to $G$)

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry, I don't know if I understood it. I have to use the implicit function theorem to prove the existence of H(x,y)? I don't need the inverse function theorem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need the inverse function theorem and you even don't need $G$ to exist. You can use directly the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @AnneBauval ok, thank you!